# VB.NET: VBA PowerPoint constant not declared

Tags: vb.net, interop, powerpoint

I'm experiencing a problem with Visual Basic code with .NET framework 4.7.2 running. I'm using VBA for Office (documentation) and trying to create a PowerPoint automation tool. Now I have ran into the problem that when I use the [SaveAs method](http://ppSaveAsDefault) for PowerPoint, the [constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff760025(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) I give for the parameter *File Format* is 'not declared'. I believe I have set all references correctly. Also, the SaveAs method normally works, except when I try to specify the *File Format*, it throws this error:

[image]

The code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each sSourceFile As String In sFileLocations
        Dim pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        pptApp.visible = True

        Dim sSourcePath = Mid(sSourceFile, 1, InStrRev(sSourceFile, "\"))
        Dim sDestPattern = Mid(sSourceFile, InStrRev(sSourceFile, "\") + 1)
        Dim sDestinationFile = Replace(sDestPattern, ".pptx", "", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text)
        sDestinationFile = Replace(sDestinationFile, ".ppt", "", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text)

        Dim pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(sSourceFile)

        ' Debug.WriteLine(sSourcePath)
        ' Debug.WriteLine(sDestinationFile)

        pptPres.SaveAs(sSourcePath & sDestinationFile & ".pptx", ppSaveAsDefault)


        ' Update PowerPoint thubmnail by adding new slide to the front then saving file
        Dim pptLayout = pptPres.Slides(1).CustomLayout
        Dim newSlide = pptPres.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout)
        pptPres.save()

        ' Remove new slide and save again to display correct thumbnail
        Dim removeSlide = pptPres.Slides(1).Delete
        pptPres.save()

        pptPres.close()
        pptApp.quit()
        pptPres = Nothing
        pptApp = Nothing
    Next
    MsgBox("Done")
End Sub
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019. These are the references for the project:

[image]

How can I declare the file format with the SaveAs method successfully?

Comment: You need a reference to the PowerPoint library.

Comment: Also, please consider *pasting* your code rather than a screenshot of your code. Screenshots make it difficult for others to try and reproduce the problem without manually re-typing all of your code (which practically nobody is inclined to do!). Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens thank you for the information. I dind't know there was a specific library for PowerPoint VBA, but now I do. I will mark the question as answered (when I can). Also I will add the code to my questions now, thanks!

Comment: Yep, there's a specific library for each of the Office Applications (Excel, Word, Outlook, Access, etc.). You can do it without the library (known as late binding) but you need to declare your own constants that way.

Comment: change PpSaveAsDefault‎ to 11, or you make private const of PpSaveAsDefault = ‎11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called an `Enumeration` - You can include them by adding a PowerPoint reference to your project, or if you are using late binding, you can either replace it with the number it represents (in this case, the number 11), or create your own custom `Enumeration`.

Here is a link to that `Enumeration` - [ppSaveAsType Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppsaveasfiletype)